# Format a text file data in a desired way

Tags: matrix, text, formatting, format, converters

I have a huge text file containing formatted data as shown below

[image]

Now I want to extract the first two fields and save it in a separate text or any other format like spreadsheet or anything else which should look like this

50756,4f5e3a72e4b053fd6a4313f6

190571,4b4b87b5f964a5204a9f26e3

221021,4a85b1b3f964a520eefe1fe3

66981,4b4606f2f964a520751426e3

21010,4c2b4e8a9a559c74832f0de2

28761,4b4bade2f964a520cfa326e3

39350,49bbd6c0f964a520f4531fe3

1446,4e88cf4ed22d53877981fdab

82296,4dfc825bc65b31579b2e7679

because I have to use it as an **input matrix** to a python program.How do I do that?

Comment: How long is the text file? What language are you planning/wanting to use to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you could:

```
cat input_file.txt | awk '{ print $1","$2 }' > output_file.txt
```

In Python, you could:

```
with open("input_file.txt", "r") as input_file:
    with open("output_file.txt", "w") as output_file:
        for line in input_file.readlines():
            items = line.split()
            output_file.write(items[0] + "," + items[1] + "\n")
```

I'd bet someone who writes Python everyday can probably come along and do that even cleaner, too. Any takers?